# Navbar is shifting to the left and the Bootstrap sign-in example is distorted on Flask. Any fixes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Navbar has been shifted to the left, and has distorted login items, which is a bootstrap example.

I have a file called login.html in which I have used the bootstrap sign-in bootstrap example. For some reason, only on this page, the navbar seems to shift on the left, and the bootstrap example is kind of shifted to the right. I suspect that it is something to do with the core bootstrap CSS, but I don't want to touch those files and so I am looking for an alternative method to fix this problem. This is the image of the how page looks like:

[image: img1]

Also note that the way I have imported bootstrap css is by saving the css and js bootstrap folders in a static folder(as I am using flask)

here is my base.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--NAVBAR STARTS-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="nav-link cypherlearn" href="{{ url_for('views.home') }}">CypherLearn</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          {% if user is defined and user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto ">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('views.home') }}">
            
                <img  class="backtohome" id="backtohome" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.png') }}">
            </a>
              
            </li>
            <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url_for('views.home') }}">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            
           

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url_for('views.lab') }}">Lab</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url_for('views.learn') }}">
                Learn
              </a>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url_for('views.puzzles') }}">Puzzles</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a>

            </li>
              
            </ul>
            {%else %}
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"href="{{ url_for('auth.signup') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user "></span>Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link"href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
              </ul>
              {%endif%}
          
         </div> 
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!--NAVBAR ENDS!-->
      {% with messages=get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true)%}
      {%if messages%}
      {%for category,message in messages%}
      {%if category=="invalid"%}
      <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade show " role="alert">
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade show " role="alert">
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      {% endif%}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
      
      
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="container main-content">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

login.html code:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block title%}
 Login
 {%endblock%}
 {% block content %}
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">








<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/static/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="text-center">

<main class="form-signin">
<form method="POST">
<img class="mb-4" src="/static/logo.png" alt="" width="72" height="57">
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Sign In</h1>

<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
  <label for="email">Email address</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox mb-3">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
  </label>
</div>
<button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>

</form>
</main>








 {% endblock %}
```

styles.css:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.backtohome {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.cypherlearn {
  padding: 0px;
}

.signup {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.navbar {
  background: #0a465d !important;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

/*DROPDOWN LAB */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.navbar {
  background: #0a465d !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

/*LOGIN PAGE*/
.bd-placeholder-img {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}

.main-content {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.body {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!
Thank you for your detailed question; I checked the image you posted regarding how the website is currently looking, however I'm not sure how do you want it to be exactly. Can you please post a 2nd image (or other visual media) to make it clearer?

Comment: @underflow i just want it so the navbar sticks at the top horizontally, and the login and password and the logo are in the center of the page.

Comment: it would be helpful if you add the project structure

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app is not able to read the BS CSS file in the login page thus the display of the navbar. Please replace the `<link>` tag on the login page with the cdn:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In addition, if you want to stick on your local BS CSS (in the static folder), I believe that the correct path shouldn't start with the word static:

```html
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: it has not made a difference.

Comment: If it helps, when i refresh the page, i can see the navbar as normal horizontally on the page only for about a millisecond, and then it again takes the shape of how the page is shown in the image.

Comment: Comment your link tag CSS to see what happens